# Facebook Custom Page

Tags: facebook, web

I'm wondering what's the best way to create a Facebook page where users can upload their pictures to participate in a poll, allow their friends to participate, and allow the admin to see the votes?

Should I build my own PHP web application, and use Facebook iFrames?

Is there a better way to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should build your own PHP web application and then use an iFrame Canvas page on Facebook. Just put your app as the Canvas URL:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/tutorial/

You can create both a Canvas app (full screen) or tab app (smaller app) this way!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You should build application that will run in Facebook Page tab (canvas of tab is loaded as an iframe)